# Issues Extracting Data from XML files using R

Tags: xml, r, parsing

I have a large database of proteins in an xml file that I need to extract some information from using R. The database is organized by entries, which contain information about the specific protein that I need to extract and format.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dq8ir9f22cnfwrz/Sample.xml

I would like to extract the name, all the dbReferences that are type "EC", and the sequence for each entry. So far I have:

```
library("XML")
doc <- xmlParse("Sample.xml")
```

I was thinking of either using the `xpathSApply` function to explicitly pick tags to go to, or the `xmlToDataFrame` function. I'm new to R, so I'm a bit confused as to where to begin.

Comment: As a starter: 3 ways to extract the dbReferences would e.g. be `unlist(doc['//*[local-name()="dbReference" and @type="EC"]/@id']); xpathSApply(doc, '//*[local-name()="dbReference" and @type="EC"]/@id'); xpathSApply(doc, '//*[local-name()="dbReference" and @type="EC"]', function(x) xmlAttrs(x)['id'])`.

Comment: that works for extracting all the EC numbers, but is there any way to organize them by which entry they belong to?

Comment: What would be the "entry" for the 1st one? Take e.g. authors and titles. There are prly be better ways, but 1 way to extract them is `nd <- getNodeSet(doc, "//ns:citation", namespaces=c(ns=getDefaultNamespace(doc)[[1]]$uri)); auth <- plyr::ldply(lapply(nd, xmlToList), data.frame); (auth <- na.omit(unique(reshape2::melt(auth, id.vars="title", measure.vars=grep("authorList", names(auth)))))[, c(1,3)])`. Looks inconvenient, but maybe anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the elements you need from getNodeSet

```
nd <- getNodeSet(doc, "//ns:entry", namespaces=c(ns=getDefaultNamespace(doc)[[1]]$uri))
y <- data.frame( id = sapply(nd, xpathSApply, './*[local-name()="name"]', xmlValue),
        ec = sapply(nd,  function(y) paste( xpathSApply(y, './/*[local-name()="dbReference" and @type="EC"]/@id'), collapse="; ")),
 sequence =  gsub("\n", "", sapply(nd, xpathSApply, './*[local-name()="sequence"]', xmlValue)))

head(y, 3)
           id                                                                      ec                                         sequence  
1 AK1C3_HUMAN 1.-.-.-; 1.1.1.357; 1.1.1.112; 1.1.1.188; 1.1.1.239; 1.1.1.64; 1.3.1.20  MDSKHQCVKLNDGHFMPVLGFGTYAPPEVPRSKALEVTKLAIEA...
2 CP3A4_HUMAN              1.14.13.-; 1.14.13.157; 1.14.13.32; 1.14.13.67; 1.14.13.97  MALIPDLAMETWLLLAVSLVLLYLYGTHSHGLFKKLGIPGPTPL...
3 AK1C1_HUMAN                                 1.1.1.-; 1.1.1.149; 1.1.1.112; 1.3.1.20  MDSKYQCVKLNDGHFMPVLGFGTYAPAEVPKSKALEATKLAIEA...
```

You could also drop the namespace and simplify these queries...

```
x <- readLines("Sample.xml")
x[2] <- "<uniprot>"
doc <- xmlParse(x)
nd <- getNodeSet(doc, "//entry")
```

OR use the Rest services from Uniprot instead

http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=AK1C3_HUMAN+OR+CP3A4_HUMAN+OR+AK1C1_HUMAN&format=tab&columns=entry%20name,ec,sequence