# Extracting multiple attribute data from XML nodes using R

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to pull multiple attribute datasets from multiple nodes in an XML, however have become stuck just trying to pull any attribute data at all from my XML. I want to pull all attribute data from "feature" nodes together but keep returning empty lists.

I've based my code so far on one from this answer:
[R XML select 2 attributes from a same node xmlAttrs()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319376/r-xml-select-2-attributes-from-a-same-node-xmlattrs)

However whilst the example code (below, bottom) works perfectly and the XML format looks very similar to my data and my needs, the code when adapted to my data returns empty lists (below, top).

```
##doesn't work
doc<- xmlParse("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/p05067.xml")
sapply(c("feature type", "description"), function(x) xpathSApply(doc, '/feature', xmlGetAttr, x))

#works
exdoc <- xmlParse("http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObjectAttachment.action?uri=info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0084312&representation=XML")
sapply(c("contrib-type","xlink:type"), function(x) xpathSApply(exdoc, '//contrib', xmlGetAttr, x))
```

Output for #works

```
    contrib-type xlink:type
[1,] "author"     "simple"  
[2,] "author"     "simple"  
[3,] "author"     "simple"  
[4,] "author"     "simple"  
[5,] "author"     "simple"  
[6,] "editor"     "simple"
```

Comment: First, you have a typo in the first example: `rootdoc` should be `doc`. Second, if that is not the problem can you show what you expect from the output?

Comment: Third, There is no `feature type` field. There is `feature` with a `type` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, that is a typo, this code has undergone many itterations. Updated the post with the output

Answer (score 0):

This gets you pretty close to where you need to be I think. XML and xpath are black magic to me. Credit to this post: [Issues Extracting Data from XML files using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838760/issues-extracting-data-from-xml-files-using-r)

```
library(XML)

doc1 <- xmlParse("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/p05067.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)

nd <- getNodeSet(doc1, "//ns:feature", namespaces=c(ns=getDefaultNamespace(doc1)[[1]]$uri))
y <- list(type=xmlApply(nd, xmlGetAttr, name="type"),
                desc = xmlApply(nd, xmlGetAttr, name="description"))
```